# Audio hardware setting - Line-In

Tags: audio, operating-system

I have an application requirement where certain audio settings need to be made at the hardware level rather than the session level. I have been able to hit most of the areas in question using a third party API. However, a new requirement has come up and I'm having trouble accessing the setting.

We are primarily on Win7 systems though Win10 is not out of scope. We need to be able to disable Line-In as it appears to be causing some interference with the later run session recordings that are made.

Our working environment includes multiple systems/locations. The application that handles recordings is specialized and cannot be changed for something like a base setting. Also, with newer systems the line-in and rear microphone are a combined plug and, when used, the OS asks which way you want to use it.

I realize that changing audio settings and the hardware level can be problematic but any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as this project needs to completed as quickly as possible.

Comment: You have tagged your question **core-audio**. Here's the tag's description: _Core Audio is a low-level API for dealing with sound in Apple's Mac OS X and iOS operating systems_. Could you please explain what does it have to do with **Win7 and Win10** or what does your question  have to do with _Apple's Mac OS X and iOS operating systems_? Thanks.

Comment: My reference to Core Audio is for a third party Windows API which was referenced above. The point is for any way, using that or some other API, to programmatically turn off line-in as described above.

Comment: I don't mean to be smart with this. I don't give opinions. I only refer to tags **as described within StackOverflow**, and this is **not** a tag about a third-party Windows API, which you could have read yourself. Your post ended in the wrong address. Would you please remove the tag **core-audio** from your post? Thanks.